# How to make an array of buttons and put it on a panel that matches the size of the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am doing a Minesweeper in C #, just need to generate an array of buttons and put this array inside a panel. But the array size changes according to the difficulty, in easy 8x8, 16x16 in the medium, for example. How could I generate this matrix according to the difficulty, and adjust the size of my panel (or window) with the size (dimension) of the array, having access to every button [i, j]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Button[][] InitButtonArray(int width, int height)
    {
        Button[][] btnArr = new Button[width][];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            btnArr[x] = new Button[height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                btnArr[x][y] = new Button();
            }   
        }
        return btnArr;
    }
    public void AdjustPanelSize(Panel panel,int buttonWith, int buttonHeight, int width, int height)
    {
        panel.Size = new Size(buttonWith * width, buttonHeight * height);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Let's see if I understand correctly, in `InitButtonArray(int width, int height)` I pass the size of the array. In `AdjustPanelSize(Panel panel, int buttonWith, int ButtonHeight, int width, int height)`, I pass the panel created, the size of each button, and the size of my panel, right?

Comment: You obviously have to register click event too and associate some custom data with button so that its row and col can be determined.

Comment: @Jefferson buttonWidth is the width of the button, buttonHeight is the height of the button, width is the number of buttons in x direction, height is the number of buttons in y direction.